# c++ Program skips through lines while taking input [console application]

Tags: c++, function, struct, console, console-application

I am writing a sequential program on **Library Management System** which consists of ***two structs (books and student) and several functions***.

Everything works accordingly except when I try to take **console input** in the function **add_new_book()** for the **struct book** , it skips line while taking input. I did research previously and then used the function **cin.ignore()** . That function works for the first two string inputs but after taking first two inputs, it skips the remaining input lines and terminates the function.

***Here below is code from struct book and function add_new_book()***

```
struct books{
    int book_id;
    string book_name;
    string author_name;
    string subject;
    int fine;

};

void add_new_book(){

    struct books b;
    cout << "Enter the Book Name : "; 
    getline(cin, b.book_name);
    cin.ignore();
    //cin >> b.book_name;
    cout << "Enter Author's Name : ";
    getline(cin, b.author_name);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter Book id : ";
    cin >> b.book_id;

    cout << "Enter Book Cost : ";
    cin >> b.fine;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter the Subject : ";
    getline(cin, b.subject);

    cout << "\n",b.book_name,b.author_name,b.book_id,b.fine,b.subject;
            cout << "\n\n\t\t SUCCUSSFULLY ADDED \n";
    // open a file in write mode.
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("book1.txt");
    outfile << b.book_name << endl;
    outfile.close();
    admin();
}
```

Comment: 1. Please fix the strange indentation and extraneous blank lines in your code.  2.  I don't know what you think `cout << "\n%25s %25s %25s %25d %25d                        
   %25s",b.book_name,b.author_name,b.book_id,b.fine,b.subject;` does, but it is a long winded way of saying `cout << b.subject;`.  If you crank your compiler warning level up to maximum, it will complain about it.

Comment: 3: `struct books b`:  This is C++, you can just write `books b;` - also, I would name the class with the singular (use the plural for a container of multiple books) - so `book b`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to get rid of `cin.ignore`'s and  use getline for numeric fields as well, using a std::string as a temporary buffer:

```
string s;
cout << "Enter Book id : ";
//cin >> b.book_id;
getline(cin, s);
```

Once you have the user input in a string, check its value and eventually assign it to the struct field, e.g. the book id has to be converted to int, this way:

```
b.book_id = std::atoi(s.c_str());
```

atoi will return zero if no conversion can be performed

```
if(b.book_id == 0)
{
   cout << "Invalid book id";
}
```

Also, `cout` is not meant to be used the way you do. I would try something clean and tidy, like this:

```
cout << "Title : " << b.book_name << endl;
cout << "Author: " << b.author_name << endl;
//etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You you shouldn't call [`std::cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  `getline` will extract the `'\n'` from the input stream at the end of the line.  Calling `ignore` will extract and discard *another* line.

Comment: That's what I did before. But it then even skips the string input as well

Comment: @AhmedAdnan You do know you still only print `b.subject`?